# Expo Android Build Error with react-native-text-recognition: "Could not determine the dependencies of null

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm working on an Expo project with managed workflow and recently added the react-native-text-recognition module to my project. After adding this module, I started encountering build issues on Android, while iOS continues to work fine.

Here's the relevant part of the error message I'm receiving:

:react-native-google-mobile-ads package.json found at /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-google-mobile-ads/package.json

:react-native-google-mobile-ads:version set from package.json: 12.3.0 (12,3,0 - 12003000)

:react-native-google-mobile-ads:android.compileSdk using custom value: 31

:react-native-google-mobile-ads:android.targetSdk using custom value: 31

:react-native-google-mobile-ads:android.minSdk using custom value: 21

:react-native-google-mobile-ads:reactNativeAndroidDir /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native/android

Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses

License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 accepted.

Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)".

"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" ready.

Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/build-tools/30.0.3

"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" complete.

"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" finished.

Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 31 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses

License for package Android SDK Platform 31 accepted.

Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 31 (revision: 1)".

"Install Android SDK Platform 31 (revision: 1)" ready.

Installing Android SDK Platform 31 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-31

"Install Android SDK Platform 31 (revision: 1)" complete.

"Install Android SDK Platform 31 (revision: 1)" finished.

Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 31 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses

License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 31 accepted.

Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 31 (revision: 31.0.0)".

"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 31 (revision: 31.0.0)" ready.

Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 31 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/build-tools/31.0.0

"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 31 (revision: 31.0.0)" complete.

"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 31 (revision: 31.0.0)" finished.

WARNING:The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (29.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (30.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 7.4.2.

Android SDK Build Tools 30.0.3 will be used.

To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

WARNING:The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (29.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (30.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 7.4.2.

Android SDK Build Tools 30.0.3 will be used.

To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-text-recognition:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles'.

> Could not determine the dependencies of null.

> Could not create task ':react-native-text-recognition:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

```
  > In order to compile Java 9+ source, please set compileSdkVersion to 30 or above
```

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 27s

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

So i tried to use expo-build-properties, but it did'nt help here is the pacakge.json:

```
{
  "name": "cardvault",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "format": "prettier --ignore-path .gitignore --write \"**/*.+(js|ts|json)\"",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "~7.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "card-validator": "^8.1.1",
    "crypto-es": "^2.0.4",
    "eas-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.52.0",
    "eslint-config-universe": "^12.0.0",
    "expo": "~49.0.11",
    "expo-application": "~5.3.0",
    "expo-build-properties": "^0.8.3",
    "expo-camera": "^13.6.0",
    "expo-clipboard": "~4.3.1",
    "expo-constants": "^14.4.2",
    "expo-device": "~5.4.0",
    "expo-document-picker": "~11.5.4",
    "expo-image-picker": "^14.5.0",
    "expo-local-authentication": "~13.4.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.20.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-print": "~12.4.2",
    "expo-secure-store": "~12.3.1",
    "expo-sharing": "~11.5.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.17",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.9",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^12.3.0",
    "react-native-keychain": "^8.1.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.10.5",
    "react-native-root-siblings": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-text-recognition": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-view-shot": "3.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "lint-staged": {
    "**/*": "prettier --w . --ignore-unknown",
    "*.{ts,tsx}": "eslint"
  }
}
```

here is app.json:

```
{
  "name": "CardVault",
  "slug": "cardvault",
  "version": "1.5.2",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
  "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
  "splash": {
    "image": "./assets/splash.png",
    "resizeMode": "contain",
    "backgroundColor": "#000"
  },
  "assetBundlePatterns": [
    "**/*"
  ],
  "ios": {
    "supportsTablet": true,
    "bundleIdentifier": "com.bhaumik.tandan.cardvault",
    "buildNumber": "12"
  },
  "android": {
    "adaptiveIcon": {
      "foregroundImage": "./assets/icon.png",
      "backgroundColor": "#000"
    },
    "package": "com.bhaumik.tandan.cardvault",
    "versionCode": 12
  },
  "web": {
    "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
  },
  "extra": {
    "eas": {
      "projectId": "f26cf6f9-5809-4aa2-bf74-370cdbacf72e"
    }
  },
  "owner": "cardvault",
  "plugins": [
    [
      "expo-build-properties",
      {
        "android": {
          "compileSdkVersion": 31,
          "targetSdkVersion": 31,
          "buildToolsVersion": "31.0.0"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "sdkVersion": "49.0.0",
  "platforms": [
    "ios",
    "android"
  ]
}
```

here is eas.json:

```js
{
    "cli": {
        "version": ">= 5.2.0",
        "promptToConfigurePushNotifications": false
    },
    "build": {
        "development": {
            "releaseChannel": "staging",
            "distribution": "internal",
            "android": {
                "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug"
            },
            "ios": {
                "cocoapods": "1.11.2",
                "enterpriseProvisioning": "adhoc"
            },
            "env": {
                "ENV": "development"
            }
        },
        "staging": {
            "releaseChannel": "staging",
            "distribution": "internal",
            "android": {
                "buildType": "apk"
            },
            "ios": {
                "cocoapods": "1.11.2",
                "enterpriseProvisioning": "adhoc"
            },
            "env": {
                "ENV": "staging"
            }
        },
        "productionTest": {
            "releaseChannel": "staging",
            "distribution": "internal",
            "android": {
                "buildType": "apk"
            },
            "ios": {
                "cocoapods": "1.11.2",
                "enterpriseProvisioning": "adhoc"
            },
            "env": {
                "ENV": "productionTest"
            }
        },
        "production": {
            "distribution": "store",
            "releaseChannel": "main",
            "android": {
                "buildType": "app-bundle"
            },
            "cache": {
                "key": "Invalidate"
            },
            "ios": {
                "cocoapods": "1.11.2",
                "enterpriseProvisioning": "universal"
            },
            "env": {
                "ENV": "production"
            }
        }
    },
    "submit": {
        "production": {}
    }
}
```